# Button zoom onMouseover in richFaces

Tags: richfaces

For the below code how to add onmouseover functionality in richFaces

```
 <a4j:region id="auditbutton">                      
 <a4j:commandButton id="audit" image="images/audit.png" 
    action="#{agentBean.retrieveAuditInformation}"  oncomplete="javascript:popopen()"  status="ajaxStatus"> 
<rich:toolTip for="audit" value="View History" direction="top-left" styleClass="tooltip"/>  
       </a4j:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a4j:commandButton ...... onmouseover="this.width = this.width + 5;" onmouseout="this.width = this.width - 5;">
```

Comment: I want to add mouseover()/mouneout functionality to the image only in that button.

Comment: Sorry I can't understand. When you use `<a4j:commandButton>` with `image` attribute, final `HTML` out will be an `<input type="image"...>` element. Above code increase the size of it by `5`.

Comment: its increasing the whole <td> in the table.i need to zoom the image only in the command button. my code is like below<h:panelgrid><h:form><a4j:regoin><a4j:commandbutton id="a" image=audit.png" action="" onmouseover=""</a4j:commandbutton></a4j:region></h:form></h:panelgrid>